# APR_MD5 in ObjectiveC

Tags: ios, objective-c, apache, encryption

I use to encrypt NSString using CommonCrypto library on iOS (http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto-36064/CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h).

Now, I would like to encrypt NSString using APR_MD5, which is the preferred way to encrypt passwords in .htpasswd in Apache. I found this http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/apr/apr-12/apr-util/apr-util/crypto/apr_md5.c but no example is provided. Anyone had experience with this library?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Hash functions such as MD5 do not perform "encryption", they create an "Cryptographic Hash". The point is it is a oneway function, there is no reverse or decryption available from a hash

Comment: Another Best Practice to create password hashes is [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) which is provided by CommonCrypto: `CommonKeyDerivation.h`.